# Unable to connect to SQL Server in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried to make a mail service with connection to the SQL Server, 
when I reached

```
 con.open(); //where con is the sqlconnection string
```

It said:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I tried to enable tcp/ip, checked all services and it were enabled!
and even I gave permissions to own user (me). Still it didn't work!

What can I do now ?

Comment: try `telnet ip 1433`

Comment: are you able to connect to the database from SQL server management studio.

Comment: do you close the conn after you finished using it?

Comment: @Manish i am able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am solving that problem by opening Services then start running SQL Server (SqlExpress) service.

[image]